# Facebook has detected App isn't using a secure connection to transfer information

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

Giving the following errors while login to Facebook using javascript sdk

error Facebook has detected Review Refer App isn't using a secure connection to transfer information.

Please refer the screen shot
http://prntscr.com/p11bi6

Comment: Your site needs to be in `https://` to use facebook login

Comment: How do I do that sir ??

Comment: You can do that from facebook developer console under your facebook app

Comment: Using ngrok for development would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried most of the solutions I found, to no avail. I realised in my case that it was a SSL issue.
The following steps completely fixed this issue for me:

In your Package.json >

```
"start": "set HTTPS=true&&set SSL_CRT_FILE=cert.pem&&set SSL_KEY_FILE=key.pem&&set REACT_APP_ENV=dev&& react-scripts start"
```

Create SSL Cert

```
1. Define SSL Config.
 Save the following as req.conf:

 [req]
 distinguished_name = Companyname
 x509_extensions = v3_req
 prompt = no
 [Companyname]
 C = US
 ST = VA
 L = SomeCity
 O = Companyname
 OU = MyDivision
 CN = www.Companyname.com
 [v3_req]
 keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
 extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
 subjectAltName = @alt_names
 [alt_names]
 DNS.1 = localhost
 DNS.2 = other

2. Run CMD
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 730 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -config req.conf -extensions 'v3_req'

3. Import certificate into Trusted certificate store
3.1 Convert to pfx with following CMD
openssl pkcs12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -export -out cert.pfx

3.2 Run certmgr and import the pfx certificate into personal and Trusted Root certificate stores
```

This worked for me, i hope it helps.